# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in joomla php

Tags: arrays, foreach

I got this the follow error:
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\home\acesseecom1\Web\libraries\joomla\access\access.php on line 409

The code is:

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

jimport('joomla.utilities.arrayhelper');

/**
 * Class that handles all access authorisation routines.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Access
 * @since       11.1
 */
class JAccess
{
    /**
     * Array of view levels
     *
     * @var    array
     * @since  11.1
     */
    protected static $viewLevels = array();

```
/**
 * Array of rules for the asset
 *
 * @var    array
 * @since  11.1
 */
protected static $assetRules = array();

/**
 * Array of user groups.
 *
 * @var    array
 * @since  11.1
 */
protected static $userGroups = array();

/**
 * Array of user group paths.
 *
 * @var    array
 * @since  11.1
 */
protected static $userGroupPaths = array();

/**
 * Array of cached groups by user.
 *
 * @var    array
 * @since  11.1
 */
protected static $groupsByUser = array();

/**
 * Method for clearing static caches.
 *
 * @return  void
 *
 * @since   11.3
 */
public static function clearStatics()
{
    self::$viewLevels = array();
    self::$assetRules = array();
    self::$userGroups = array();
    self::$userGroupPaths = array();
    self::$groupsByUser = array();
}

/**
 * Method to check if a user is authorised to perform an action, optionally on an asset.
 *
 * @param   integer  $userId  Id of the user for which to check authorisation.
 * @param   string   $action  The name of the action to authorise.
 * @param   mixed    $asset   Integer asset id or the name of the asset as a string.  Defaults to the global asset node.
 *
 * @return  boolean  True if authorised.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function check($userId, $action, $asset = null)
{
    // Sanitise inputs.
    $userId = (int) $userId;

    $action = strtolower(preg_replace('#[\s\-]+#', '.', trim($action)));
    $asset = strtolower(preg_replace('#[\s\-]+#', '.', trim($asset)));

    // Default to the root asset node.
    if (empty($asset))
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $assets = JTable::getInstance('Asset', 'JTable', array('dbo' => $db));
        $rootId = $assets->getRootId();
        $asset = $rootId;
    }

    // Get the rules for the asset recursively to root if not already retrieved.
    if (empty(self::$assetRules[$asset]))
    {
        self::$assetRules[$asset] = self::getAssetRules($asset, true);
    }

    // Get all groups against which the user is mapped.
    $identities = self::getGroupsByUser($userId);
    array_unshift($identities, $userId * -1);

    return self::$assetRules[$asset]->allow($action, $identities);
}

/**
 * Method to check if a group is authorised to perform an action, optionally on an asset.
 *
 * @param   integer  $groupId  The path to the group for which to check authorisation.
 * @param   string   $action   The name of the action to authorise.
 * @param   mixed    $asset    Integer asset id or the name of the asset as a string.  Defaults to the global asset node.
 *
 * @return  boolean  True if authorised.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function checkGroup($groupId, $action, $asset = null)
{
    // Sanitize inputs.
    $groupId = (int) $groupId;
    $action = strtolower(preg_replace('#[\s\-]+#', '.', trim($action)));
    $asset = strtolower(preg_replace('#[\s\-]+#', '.', trim($asset)));

    // Get group path for group
    $groupPath = self::getGroupPath($groupId);

    // Default to the root asset node.
    if (empty($asset))
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $assets = JTable::getInstance('Asset', 'JTable', array('dbo' => $db));
        $rootId = $assets->getRootId();
    }

    // Get the rules for the asset recursively to root if not already retrieved.
    if (empty(self::$assetRules[$asset]))
    {
        self::$assetRules[$asset] = self::getAssetRules($asset, true);
    }

    return self::$assetRules[$asset]->allow($action, $groupPath);
}

/**
 * Gets the parent groups that a leaf group belongs to in its branch back to the root of the tree
 * (including the leaf group id).
 *
 * @param   mixed  $groupId  An integer or array of integers representing the identities to check.
 *
 * @return  mixed  True if allowed, false for an explicit deny, null for an implicit deny.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
protected static function getGroupPath($groupId)
{
    // Preload all groups
    if (empty(self::$userGroups))
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('parent.id, parent.lft, parent.rgt')
            ->from('#__usergroups AS parent')
            ->order('parent.lft');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        self::$userGroups = $db->loadObjectList('id');
    }

    // Make sure groupId is valid
    if (!array_key_exists($groupId, self::$userGroups))
    {
        return array();
    }

    // Get parent groups and leaf group
    if (!isset(self::$userGroupPaths[$groupId]))
    {
        self::$userGroupPaths[$groupId] = array();

        foreach (self::$userGroups as $group)
        {
            if ($group->lft <= self::$userGroups[$groupId]->lft && $group->rgt >= self::$userGroups[$groupId]->rgt)
            {
                self::$userGroupPaths[$groupId][] = $group->id;
            }
        }
    }

    return self::$userGroupPaths[$groupId];
}

/**
 * Method to return the JAccessRules object for an asset.  The returned object can optionally hold
 * only the rules explicitly set for the asset or the summation of all inherited rules from
 * parent assets and explicit rules.
 *
 * @param   mixed    $asset      Integer asset id or the name of the asset as a string.
 * @param   boolean  $recursive  True to return the rules object with inherited rules.
 *
 * @return  JAccessRules   JAccessRules object for the asset.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function getAssetRules($asset, $recursive = false)
{
    // Get the database connection object.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Build the database query to get the rules for the asset.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($recursive ? 'b.rules' : 'a.rules');
    $query->from('#__assets AS a');
    //sqlsrv change
    $query->group($recursive ? 'b.id, b.rules, b.lft' : 'a.id, a.rules, a.lft');

    // If the asset identifier is numeric assume it is a primary key, else lookup by name.
    if (is_numeric($asset))
    {
        $query->where('(a.id = ' . (int) $asset . ')');
    }
    else
    {
        $query->where('(a.name = ' . $db->quote($asset) . ')');
    }

    // If we want the rules cascading up to the global asset node we need a self-join.
    if ($recursive)
    {
        $query->leftJoin('#__assets AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft AND b.rgt >= a.rgt');
        $query->order('b.lft');
    }

    // Execute the query and load the rules from the result.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadColumn();

    // Get the root even if the asset is not found and in recursive mode
    if (empty($result))
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $assets = JTable::getInstance('Asset', 'JTable', array('dbo' => $db));
        $rootId = $assets->getRootId();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('rules');
        $query->from('#__assets');
        $query->where('id = ' . $db->quote($rootId));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();
        $result = array($result);
    }
    // Instantiate and return the JAccessRules object for the asset rules.
    $rules = new JAccessRules;
    $rules->mergeCollection($result);

    return $rules;
}

/**
 * Method to return a list of user groups mapped to a user. The returned list can optionally hold
 * only the groups explicitly mapped to the user or all groups both explicitly mapped and inherited
 * by the user.
 *
 * @param   integer  $userId     Id of the user for which to get the list of groups.
 * @param   boolean  $recursive  True to include inherited user groups.
 *
 * @return  array    List of user group ids to which the user is mapped.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function getGroupsByUser($userId, $recursive = true)
{
    // Creates a simple unique string for each parameter combination:
    $storeId = $userId . ':' . (int) $recursive;

    if (!isset(self::$groupsByUser[$storeId]))
    {
        // Guest user (if only the actually assigned group is requested)
        if (empty($userId) && !$recursive)
        {
            $result = array(JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users')->get('guest_usergroup', 1));
        }
        // Registered user and guest if all groups are requested
        else
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();

            // Build the database query to get the rules for the asset.
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select($recursive ? 'b.id' : 'a.id');
            if (empty($userId))
            {
                $query->from('#__usergroups AS a');
                $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users')->get('guest_usergroup', 1));
            }
            else
            {
                $query->from('#__user_usergroup_map AS map');
                $query->where('map.user_id = ' . (int) $userId);
                $query->leftJoin('#__usergroups AS a ON a.id = map.group_id');
            }

            // If we want the rules cascading up to the global asset node we need a self-join.
            if ($recursive)
            {
                $query->leftJoin('#__usergroups AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft AND b.rgt >= a.rgt');
            }

            // Execute the query and load the rules from the result.
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->loadColumn();

            // Clean up any NULL or duplicate values, just in case
            JArrayHelper::toInteger($result);

            if (empty($result))
            {
                $result = array('1');
            }
            else
            {
                $result = array_unique($result);
            }
        }

        self::$groupsByUser[$storeId] = $result;
    }

    return self::$groupsByUser[$storeId];
}

/**
 * Method to return a list of user Ids contained in a Group
 *
 * @param   integer  $groupId    The group Id
 * @param   boolean  $recursive  Recursively include all child groups (optional)
 *
 * @return  array
 *
 * @since   11.1
 * @todo    This method should move somewhere else
 */
public static function getUsersByGroup($groupId, $recursive = false)
{
    // Get a database object.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $test = $recursive ? '>=' : '=';

    // First find the users contained in the group
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('DISTINCT(user_id)');
    $query->from('#__usergroups as ug1');
    $query->join('INNER', '#__usergroups AS ug2 ON ug2.lft' . $test . 'ug1.lft AND ug1.rgt' . $test . 'ug2.rgt');
    $query->join('INNER', '#__user_usergroup_map AS m ON ug2.id=m.group_id');
    $query->where('ug1.id=' . $db->Quote($groupId));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->loadColumn();

    // Clean up any NULL values, just in case
    JArrayHelper::toInteger($result);

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Method to return a list of view levels for which the user is authorised.
 *
 * @param   integer  $userId  Id of the user for which to get the list of authorised view levels.
 *
 * @return  array    List of view levels for which the user is authorised.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function getAuthorisedViewLevels($userId)
{
    // Get all groups that the user is mapped to recursively.
    $groups = self::getGroupsByUser($userId);

    // Only load the view levels once.
    if (empty(self::$viewLevels))
    {
        // Get a database object.
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();

        // Build the base query.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id, rules');
        $query->from($query->qn('#__viewlevels'));

        // Set the query for execution.
        $db->setQuery((string) $query);

        // Build the view levels array.
        foreach ($db->loadAssocList() as $level)
        {
            self::$viewLevels[$level['id']] = (array) json_decode($level['rules']);
        }
    }

    // Initialise the authorised array.
    $authorised = array(1);

    // Find the authorised levels.
    foreach (self::$viewLevels as $level => $rule)
    {
        foreach ($rule as $id)
        {
            if (($id < 0) && (($id * -1) == $userId))
            {
                $authorised[] = $level;
                break;
            }
            // Check to see if the group is mapped to the level.
            elseif (($id >= 0) && in_array($id, $groups))
            {
                $authorised[] = $level;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $authorised;
}

/**
 * Method to return a list of actions for which permissions can be set given a component and section.
 *
 * @param   string  $component  The component from which to retrieve the actions.
 * @param   string  $section    The name of the section within the component from which to retrieve the actions.
 *
 * @return  array  List of actions available for the given component and section.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 *
 * @deprecated  12.3  Use JAccess::getActionsFromFile or JAccess::getActionsFromData instead.
 *
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * 
 */
public static function getActions($component, $section = 'component')
{
    JLog::add(__METHOD__ . ' is deprecated. Use JAccess::getActionsFromFile or JAcces::getActionsFromData instead.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');
    $actions = self::getActionsFromFile(
        JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/' . $component . '/access.xml',
        "/access/section[@name='" . $section . "']/"
    );
    if (empty($actions))
    {
        return array();
    }
    else
    {
        return $actions;
    }
}

/**
 * Method to return a list of actions from a file for which permissions can be set.
 *
 * @param   string  $file   The path to the XML file.
 * @param   string  $xpath  An optional xpath to search for the fields.
 *
 * @return  boolean|array   False if case of error or the list of actions available.
 *
 * @since   12.1
 */
public static function getActionsFromFile($file, $xpath = "/access/section[@name='component']/")
{
    if (!is_file($file))
    {
        // If unable to find the file return false.
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Else return the actions from the xml.
        return self::getActionsFromData(JFactory::getXML($file, true), $xpath);
    }
}

/**
 * Method to return a list of actions from a string or from an xml for which permissions can be set.
 *
 * @param   string|SimpleXMLElement  $data   The XML string or an XML element.
 * @param   string                   $xpath  An optional xpath to search for the fields.
 *
 * @return  boolean|array   False if case of error or the list of actions available.
 *
 * @since   12.1
 */
public static function getActionsFromData($data, $xpath = "/access/section[@name='component']/")
{
    // If the data to load isn't already an XML element or string return false.
    if ((!($data instanceof SimpleXMLElement)) && (!is_string($data)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Attempt to load the XML if a string.
    if (is_string($data))
    {
        $data = JFactory::getXML($data, false);

        // Make sure the XML loaded correctly.
        if (!$data)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Initialise the actions array
    $actions = array();

    // Get the elements from the xpath
    $elements = $data->xpath($xpath . 'action[@name][@title][@description]');

    // If there some elements, analyse them
    if (!empty($elements))
    {
        foreach ($elements as $action)
        {
            // Add the action to the actions array
            $actions[] = (object) array(
                'name' => (string) $action['name'],
                'title' => (string) $action['title'],
                'description' => (string) $action['description']
            );
        }
    }

    // Finally return the actions array
    return $actions;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If it's working ok simply try hide warnings with:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

on start of the file.